# Retrieve objects from JTable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, object, jtable

I filled up a JTable with data I've extracted from an Array of Objects (This array have objects which data has been retrieven from a DB with a ResultSet). When filling up the data on the JTable I don't want to show all the atributes of the object, just some of them. One of those that doesn't need to be shown is the id that correspond to the number this objects have in the DB, which is the primary key of the table. My question is; Is there a simple way to retrieve the object out of a row in the JTable, or do I have to search in the Array for the object that has atributes which matches the ones that were selected in the row of the JTable?

Comment: How did you filled up a JTable from Array? Post examples of your code.

Comment: `do I have to search in the Array `, you should not reference the array again. You should only deal with the TableModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to retrieve the object out of a row in the JTable,

You need to have a method in your TableModel that will do this. So instead of getValueAt() you need a method like `getRow(...)`.

Take a look a [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for an example of how you might do this in your TableModel. Or you could decide to use this model since is was designed to be generice in nature. You just need to implement a couple of methods for the model to only display the properties that you want to see displayed.